# Finding an irreducible polynomial over the rationals

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I'm very confused by a homework question.
"Find the irreducible polynomial for $ \sin{2\pi/5}$ over Q.
I found that $16t^{4}-20t^{2}+5=0$ but this is not monic? This is also irreducible by Eisenstein, but minimal polynomials are always monic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a monic polynomial, you can divide by $16$.  Of course it won't have integer coefficients any more.  A number that is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients is an algebraic integer.  $\sin(2\pi/5)$ is not an algebraic integer.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that algebraic elements over Q were not all algebraic integers. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1):

$p(t)=t^{4}-5/4t^{2}+5/16$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sin 2\pi/5$ over $\mathbb Q$. It is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ according to [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) as $16t^{4}-20t^{2}+5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: This isn't a polynomial in Z[X]...

Comment: @Oddlyasymmetric You're right. Corrected the typo in my answer.